# Angular 6 authentication guard

Tags: angular, authentication, frontend

I followed a tutorial about setting a JWT authentication with fake backend on my application but I'm getting stuck with the authentication. In fact, I'm just trying to access to a client panel or an "admin" panel with two differents roles which are "client" and "conseiller" for the admin one.

File : app.routing.ts

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ 
path: '',
component: AdvisorHomeComponent, 
canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
data: { 
    expectedRole: 'conseiller'
  } 
},
{
path: '',
component: ClientHomeComponent, 
canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
data: { 
  expectedRole: 'client'
  } 
}
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

// otherwise redirect to login
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

File : auth.guard.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    alert(expectedRole);
    if (currentUser && currentUser.statut == expectedRole) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url 
    }});
    return false;
 }
}
```

The mistake I noticed is that when I'm trying to login with the "conseiller" status, it works because the informations are in the first position in my configuration but If I try to login with "client" status after, it doesn't work and it's still displaying me the "conseiller" statut when I do an *alert(expectedRole);*

I think I have got something wrong in my paths setting or something like that. Be indulgent, I'm a beginner with Angular. ;)

Thanks,

Comment: may be a typo currentUser.statut  should be currentUser.status

Answer (score 0):

You have the same path (empty, default path) defined 3 times. It takes the first one.

You must define different path for client, e.g.

```
{path: 'client', component: ClientHomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { 
    expectedRole: 'client'
  } 
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I'm tried to give them a different one as you said but after that I didn't succeed in login with anyone.

So I don't really understand where I have to set their path in the application because it's the login step which brings the user to its own panel.

Comment: After successful login you should know what the role of the user is. Just redirect them to `/client` or `/conseiller`

Comment: At the end, I succeed in login with both status adding a structure condition in my login component in the OnSubmit() event. I noticed I was disturbed by this line : _this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);_ 

I don't really know if it's a "good practise" but it works with my fake backend. Maybe, it will be different when I will connect the front to the real backend !

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple ways to achieve your goals. @PeS has given you the easiest solution. I would still like to make some comments.

I would create the following:

1. app-routing.module.ts
2. auth.guard.ts
3. authentication.service.ts
4. user.service.ts
5. local-storage.service.ts
6. login.component.ts
7. home.component.ts
8. advisor-home.component.ts
9. client-home.component.ts

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to login
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

**auth.guard.ts**

Your example auth.guard.ts looks fine. You will have to edit it to get the role from a user service or something similar as oppose to the route data.

**home.component.ts**

This component will be a factory. Get the user to see what role they have and based on that role you can manually insert a specific component. So, depending on the role, you will add the `advisor-home.component.ts` or the `client-home.component.ts`. Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-example) on how to create a factory.

Comment: Thank you for replying and giving your opinion ! I think I have got many of your ideas in my code but are you talking about an implementation with real backend ? I'm asking because I have got a fake backend for the moment but I will connect my front-end to a real one soon...

Comment: No. My example is purely frontend components. You can stub the backend data into the services until you’re ready to hook up the back end.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export authGuardFn(data) {
  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      const expectedRole = data.expectedRole;
      let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      alert(expectedRole);
      if (currentUser && currentUser.statut == expectedRole) {
          // logged in so return true
          return true;
      }
  
      // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url 
      }});
      return false;
   }
  }
  return AuthGuard 
}
```